# undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have this classes.

user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  has_many :berichten
end
```

category:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :berichten
end
```

Berichten :

```
class Berichten < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :bericht, :user
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end
```

After that I created the projects.

But when I goto

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/berichtens
```

I see this message appear:

```
undefined method `user_id_contains' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::Berichten:0x007f72300bc8f0>
```

Can that be because berichten is a nested route which look like this :

```
Tamara::Application.routes.draw do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  resources  :users

  resources :category do 
     resources :berichten
  end 
 end
```

How to solve this ?

Roelof

Edit 1 : you can find the whole source tree here : https://github.com/roelof1967/tamara_site/tree/admin_section

Edit 2 : and here the development log : https://gist.github.com/3933601

Edit 3 : and here the controllers : https://gist.github.com/3937461

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I am level 1 user so I can't comment on above question. Please share your relevant controller code too. The problem is in the controller.

Comment: As I understand you right, you wish to see the berichten, category and user controller

Comment: The controller is all ok. Can you tell me the line number and file name where the error occured? And if possible share then share that file too.

Comment: Of course I can. here is the data you ask for :  NoMethodError in Admin/berichtens#index

Showing /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `user_id_contains' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::Berichten:0x00000004d83200>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)

Comment: I don't see any code related to meta_search gem in your controller or models. Then why the error is about MetaSearch? Is the code in controllers you provided complete?

Comment: I think so, Im following this tutorial : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/create-beautiful-administration-interfaces-with-active-admin/

Comment: OK. Try one of these things. Hopefully it will work.

1) Check if there is a column `"user_id"` present in berichtens table in database.

2) If the column exist there then most probably you haven't run `bundle install` after adding `meta_search` gem. So try running `bundle install`.

Comment: I see these collums : id, bericht, user, created at and updated_at. So no user_id. bundle install did not change anything

Comment: So that is the problem. The `user` column should be `user_id`.

Comment: oke, and how do I change that so I can look if thats the solution

Comment: For now you can change the column name using MySQL alter table command. And for the future you have to make changes in your migration.

Answer (score 1):

Your berichtens table has no user_id and category_id fields:
https://github.com/roelof1967/tamara_site/blob/admin_section/db/schema.rb#L49-54

Create a migration file with

```
add_column :berichtens, :user_id, :integer
add_column :berichtens, :category_id, :integer
```